# Unity changed my image asset. How do I fix this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

I imported a PNG of all of the textures I want to use in a mobile game and when I went into the sprite editor, I noticed that the edges of the sprites were "fading" into the transparent background - and the transparency changes throughout this "fade". Autodesk Sketchbook does something similar when I open the image in it, but GIMP, MS Paint, and Windows Photos don't. I was going to put pictures of what I'm talking about here, but Stack Overflow says I'm not allowed to yet. How can I fix the problem? Is there a setting in Unity that I can change so it doesn't add the "fade" or do I have to change the file format and import it again?

EDIT: I have created an Imgur album with pictures of my problem. Basically, Unity is blending the colors of the sprites and it's blending the alpha too. Also, I made the textures bigger at one point and that improved the problem, but didn't fix it completely. Here are the pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a70B.jpg

EDIT #2: First off, someone commented trying to explain what I was seeing in my imgur pictures and I asked how to fix the problem he was describing without realizing that you can't properly reply to comments, so I'm asking again, how can I fix it? Second, I just tried messing with anti-aliasing in the quality settings of my project and got this error: "Setting anti-aliasing of already created render texture is not supported!" I didn't think I had any render textures - just regular textures - but when I double-clicked the error, an unnamed render texture with an illegal size (55x110 pixels) showed up in my inspector. Changing its settings doesn't seem to do anything, but in the inspector, it still looks like it was changed. What am I seeing?

Comment: Unfortunately, pictures required.

Comment: If you don't want transparency you can turn it off via the [import settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html) -> `Alpha Source` and `Alpha is Transparency`. For further help you could upload your files manually e.g. to `imgur.com` and post links

Comment: In unity editor, in the file explorer, click on a png and look for all the parameters in the inspector. If you get enough reputation to post an image, please edit your question with :-)

Comment: You are all suggesting to turn off the transparency, but I want the background and parts of one of my textures to be transparent.

Comment: That's how a rasterized images looks when magnified with no anti-aliasing, i.e. that's the aliasing you are seeing

Comment: [bolov] So, how do I fix it?